# stickiness on painted acrylic surface

Tags: repainting

About 15 years ago I did some decorative painting on my dining room table...I coated it with polycrylic..For the past five years I have noticed a stickiness on the surface.. It is really bad during the summer months..If I put anything on it, especially paper it will stick to the table..It can be washed off, but the stickiness is awful. I read somewhere that coating it with polyurethane will solve the problem but I am nervous about that.. I have used poyyurethane over acrylic many times but not over anything that would be impossible to fix if anything went wrong........please, please, any suggestions...

Comment: So the surface coat is degrading and probably releasing some solvents as well and you want to cover that with another coating? Not sure that sounds like a good plan...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I have to agree with @SolarMike; anything on top of a badly-adhered coat will itself be badly adhered. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the finish is badly adhered, just that its surface is soft. I've seen this with latex paints, where a new coat solves the problem.

Comment: @isherwood will the polyacrylic behave like a latex paint?

Comment: I have no idea. The point was that this isn't a bonding problem.

Comment: thanks to all of you for your suggestions....I also don't think it is bonding problem..If you were to add a coat of something..would it be an oil or latex base....thanks again.